# Frequent Oxygen Sensor dirty problems (volvo diesel)

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, volvo, o2-sensor, s60

I have a volvo S60 diesel for 10 months (more than 30.000 Km), and I already have to clean the oxygen sensor once and seems that I have to clean it again.

My question is what can I do to reduce the frequency of these clean ups, since I have to leave the car in the garage for the whole day.

Do I have to replace it ?

Must I change my driving style ?

Must I use a different fuel ?

Comment: How do you use the car?  Does it frequently go on long (45min plus) journeys?

Comment: @SteveMatthews yes I daily make two highway journeys of 60minutes